# FortiGate API POST Request returns 403 Forbidden with C# RestSharp

Tags: c#, rest, curl, restsharp

I'm currently making a ASP.NET C# Web Forms application using the Fortinet API, with the intent to block certain IP addresses or URLs from it.

The C# request returns HTTP 403 Forbidden error, while the cURL request POST successfully. This only happens with POST requests: GET requests work just fine both in .NET and cURL.

According to the [documentation](http://www.tuncaybas.com/FOS_JSON_REST_API_523.pdf) I've found online, the FortiNet API validates authentication using the X-CSRFTOKEN header for a POST request, and cookies for authentication. They are included in both requests. While I debugged, I've replaced the cookie values in my cookie.txt file used in my cURL request with the same ones contained in the cookies Dictionary value, and the result is the same: it passes with cURL, not with C#.

Here's my RestSharp request:

```
private IRestResponse createAddress(Dictionary<string, string> cookies, JObject data)
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient(baseUri);
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest("api/v2/cmdb/firewall/address", Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> cookie in cookies)
    {
        request.AddCookie(cookie.Key, cookie.Value);
    }
    request.AddHeader("X-CSRFTOKEN", cookies["ccsrftoken"]);

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

    return client.Execute(request);
}
```

Here's my JSON payload, contained in the JObject data in C#, and in the params.json file for cURL:

```
{
    "vdom": "root",
    "name": "address",
    "json": {
        "type": "fqdn",
        "name": "lostininternet.com",
        "fqdn": "lostininternet.com"
    }
}
```

And here's my cURL Request:

```
curl -d "@params.json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-CSRFTOKEN: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" https://192.168.13.13/api/v2/cmdb/firewall/address/ -b cookie.txt --insecure --verbose
```

(the CSRFTOKEN value is redacted, but you get the idea...)

I've tried using HttpWebRequest instead of RestSharp, tried using a CookieContainer instead of adding them manually, with the same results every time.

Did anyone else have a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm playing with the FortiOS 5.6.5 Rest API.  I'm working with Powershell-which can include C# libraries.  The server gives you the value as a Set-Cookie value when you authenticate, but you do not send it back as a cookie.    You add the X-CSRFTOKEN as a request header.  The value is not a cookie.  Also, I found that Powershell added quotes to the string in my case, and removing the quotes fixed the issue for me.  Another thing to note-if you have the wrong path - ie, forget to add the monitor api/cmdb path, then it may return a 403 error even if the token is correct.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20671953)

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Does the following make more sense?  The csrf token is provided as a “Set-Cookie: ccsrftoken: <ccsrf token>”, when you authenticate to the firewall.  You don’t send it back as a cookie.  You send it back as a request header, like so:  X-CSRFTOKEN: <csrf token>.  The firewall expects json, so you’ll have to send the body of the request as json.  I’m using Powershell.  Be careful of extra characters that may be added when the body is converted to json.  Regarding the paths-you know what I mean if you have the documentation.